# How to make zsh CTRL-R start hh preserving user input

Tags: linux, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to use [hh](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr) utility with zsh (installed using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)).

I want to bind <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd> key to `hh` command, **passing already typed input text as `hh` argument**. Then:

- If I select some command from history and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> - run this command.
- If I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL-G</kbd> - exit from `hh` and **restore command line input text**, which was there before I pressed <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd>.

The hh utility comes with predefined zsh config:

```
# add this configuration to ~/.zshrc
export HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history  # ensure history file visibility
export HH_CONFIG=hicolor        # get more colors
bindkey -s "\C-r" "\eqhh\n"     # bind hh to Ctrl-r (for Vi mode check doc)
```

This bind works if command line is empty at the moment when I press it, but if I enter some text into command line input prompt and **then** press <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd>, then:

1. `hh` search box is empty (my command line text, entered before pressing <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd> not taken into account).
2. After manually typing some text into `hh` searchbox and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the command which runs is prefixed with the command line input text, which was entered before I pressed <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd>.

Like this:

1. Type in `apt` in zsh terminal (the command line looks like this `$ apt`) and press <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd>.
2. The `hh` is started, the search box is **empty**.
3. Type in `apt` again (this time inside `hh` searchbox), select `apt list --upgradable` from the history and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. The command line now looks like this `$ aptapt list --upgradable`. It doesn't work of course because `zsh: command not found: aptapt`.

I tried to solve this problems with custom zle widget:

```
hh-start-search() {
    TMP=$BUFFER
    zle push-input
    BUFFER="hh $TMP"
    zle accept-line
}
zle -N hh-start-search
bindkey "\C-r" hh-start-search
```

Now the first part works: the input text is passed to `hh` as first argument and it's searchbox is not empty - all good!

But then, still, when I select some command from the history and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I still get command prefixed with my previous input (so, if I select `apt install` and my input before pressing <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd> was `inst`, the command runned will be `instapt install`).

If I remove `zle push-input` from my zle widget, then command starts to work, almost all good, but then if I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> while `hh` is runned to cancel history selection, my zsh prompt is empty now (text, typed before <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd> is lost).

So, if I type in `inst` <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd>, select `apt install` from the history, and then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>, I lost my `inst` typed into zsh command prompt.

### Is there any way to make zle widget, which would do both:

1. Pass typed in text into `hh` and run selected command if I selected it.
2. Restore typed in text into command line prompt, if I decided to cancel history selection.

Comment: I guess this isn't what you're asking but I'd suggest you try [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf). It seems to do by default all that you're asking

Comment: Thanks you! I tried `fzf` and I use it more then year now. It is really good and for me it perfectly replaces `hh` (`hstr`). It has some drawbacks, though. For example, you can't delete accidentally typed wrong command from history with <kbd>DEL</kbd> key, but it is not so big drawback for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime ago installed iterm2 as a I usually do on all my Macs terminal but after I went to ohmzsh I seem to have lost my "ctrl + r" cycling through my history for some reason.

I resolved this issue on my work computer which was also installed iTerm2 but no OHMYZSH. I resolved it by remapping the keybindings in the OHMZSH config file ~/.zshrc as below :

```
#source /usr/share/doc/fzf/examples/key-bindings.zsh
bindkey -M viins 'ˆr' history-incremental-search-backward
bindkey -M vicmd 'ˆr' history-incremental-search-backward
bindkey -v
```

This didn't work on my personal laptop and can't seem to figure out what the issue is. I could try remove ohmyzsh but I'm reluctant to do that as I had customized so beautifully.